# Getting .focus() jquery on an input field to automatically display soft keyboard on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, mobile, cordova, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard

I've looked at a few tutorials around this topic and seems nearly impossible to use javascript /jquery to get the keyboard to display as soon as a user lans on the page. so far i have:

```
<textarea id="play_challenge" class="no_hover" autofocus></textarea>

 $('.message').fadeOut('fast', function(){
    $('#challenge').fadeIn('fast');
    $("#play_challenge").select();
    $("#play_challenge").focus();
    $("#play_challenge").trigger('change');
        });
```

So I'd just like to take this opportunity to ask around the question but still related. Has anyone integrated java and/or objective-c for android and ios respectively into a html/php web page? My thinking was to load the soft keyboard into my web app via any way possible. Its for a word typing game.

And also if anyone has had any good experiences with phonegap, jquerymobile, sencha or any other web app platforms with its possible expandable capabilities of such instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With or without soft keyboard, this can be done for **iOS** with cordova by adding the property

```
KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction=NO;
```

to your **Cordova.plist** file and then just **call**

```
$("textfieldID").focus();
```

You can [read more about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140484/programmatically-show-soft-keyboard-on-iphone-in-a-phonegap-application/13809533#13809533)