# Cordova.plist not found

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-2.0.0

I just "inherited" a PhoneGap 2.0.0 project, and I am trying to add a plugin.

The problem is that I don't have a cordova.plist nor a phonegap.plist nor a *.plist file

Anyone knows how is that possible ?

The project runs both in iPhone and Android and we use PhoneGap Build

Thank you all !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use PhoneGap Build so all those platform-specific files are added for you by PhoneGap Build.

What plugin are you trying to add? I think PG Build currently only has support for the ChildBrowser plugin. If you want to use any other plugin you will need to set up the development environment for each platform and create the application packages yourself.

Comment: The objective is to add the autotab function to 4 inputs in a form. I'm trying to add the plugin found on [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140484/programmatically-show-soft-keyboard-on-iphone-in-a-phonegap-application) to load the keyboard when I focus in an input. I successfully focus on the next input, but the keyboard doesn't appear

Comment: If you want to use that plugin you will have to abandon PG Build and build the projects yourself. Instructions on setting up the environment for each platform are on http://phonegap.com

Comment: I would like to use the camera API within cordova 2.0.0, in the documentation they said I will need to add it on the Cordova.plist file, but I didn't find it. Could you please point me what to do ?

Answer (score 2):

At least for android config.xml has taken over the cordova.plist file.

Hence the new entry on the config.xml should be :

< plugin name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect" value=" FacebookConnectPlugin" />

Doesn't it work ?

Comment: Yes, on iOS config.xml is also used. I couldn't find the plist file as a new user on phonegap 2.4