# Cordova: Programmatically trigger soft keyboard on wp8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, soft-keyboard

I am beginning to write an app for WP8 using Cordova. How do I show the soft keyboard without the user touching a text element? I can find soft [keyboard plugin for Android](http://plugreg.com/search?q=keyboard) and native code for [iOS plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140484/programmatically-show-soft-keyboard-on-iphone-in-a-phonegap-application) but cant find anything for WP8.

Comment: OK I ended up creating an invisible textbox, giving it focus to trigger the keyboard and handling its key events to do what I need. Works well, but I would still like to know if the keyboard can be shown without the textbox.

Comment: No. The keyboard can only be shown when entering text. Your solution sounds like a good one.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Shawn.

Comment: Is it somehow possible to invoke landscape keyboard programmatically? or change screen orientation programmatically?

Comment: @atlantis i'd suggest to post your solution as an aswer as it sounds like a good idea and solution. It would be probably easier for others to find it rather than checking comments :)

Answer (score 0):

[Posting as answer as suggested in the comments]

OK I ended up creating an invisible textbox, giving it focus to trigger the keyboard and handling its key events to do what I need. Works well, but I would still like to know if the keyboard can be shown without the textbox.